# 'XMLHTTPRequest is Undefined' IE6

Tags: php, ajax

guys, I got the error `XMLHTTPRequest is Undefined` in IE6 when I load data via ajax to another drop down in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably that's because in IE6 you'll have to create XMLHTTPRequest with ActiveXObject,

Like so:

```
   var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Comment: Thanks man that did the trick... our forum rocks....

Answer (score 1):

IE6 has no native support for XMLHTTPRequest however XMLHTTP is implemented as an ActiveX object provided by MSXML.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/01/23/516393.aspx